# Error TS1005: '(' expected in object type script with new Date()

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

I've already seen all the other posts about error TS1005. but all solutions does not worked for me

This is the code where I get this error:

```
comments: [
     {date:new Date() , message:"a" }
     ];
```

I get in in new date.

I use WebStorm 2.5.3; Angular 6, TypeScript 2.9.2

Comment: Maybe you wanted `comments = [`?

Comment: please provide  full code snippet

Comment: yes that's thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want comments as an array, it should be

```
comments= [{date:new Date() , message:"a" }];
```

Rest looks fine.

**DEMO**

```js
let comments = [
     {date:new Date() , message:"a" }
     ]; 
     
console.log(comments);
```